# How to store encrypted SecretAccessKey in registry for Redshift ODBC driver?

Tags: amazon-web-services, odbc, amazon-redshift, dsn

Ideally you create a ODBC DSN using the "ODBC Data Sources" UI.

I am creating a Redshift Driver DSN(TestDSN) using Authentication Type "IAM Credentials"

[image: Amazon Redshift ODBC Driver DSN Setup screenshot]

The settings are saved in Registry "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBC.INI\TestDSN"

The SecretAccessKey is stored encrypted
[image: (image)]

Now I want to create a DSN programmatically, and that can be done by creating Registry keys from my code [AWS documentation to Configure driver options](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/configure-odbc-connection.html#configure-odbc-options)

But the only problem is, that for Redshift Driver to use this DSN, it needs the `SecretAccessKeyEncrypted`.

How do I encrypt my SecretAccessKey to store in Registry so I can create a valid Redshift ODBC DSN?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I stumbled upon two important clues that lead me to the correct answer below.

1. The [product documentation](https://docs.rstudio.com/drivers/1.4/pdf/Simba%20ODBC%20Driver%20for%20Amazon%20Redshift%20Install%20Guide.pdf) specifies "Current User Only" or "All Users Of This Machine"... that sounds a *lot* like Data Protection Encryption [(DPAPI)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/security/how-to-use-data-protection)
2. All of the values I tried for `SecretAccessKeyEncrypted` had similar leading characters in the registry, and began with `AQAAANCMnd8BFdERjHoAwE/Cl+` (definitely uses DPAPI).

I made a Powershell script that has two functions, one for encrypting a new plaintext password into a `SecretAccessKeyEncrypted` value, and one for decrypting `SecretAccessKeyEncrypted` into plaintext.

```
### Dependencies 
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Security
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Core  


### Function Declarations
Function Decrypt-SecretAccessKey {
param (
    [string]$EncryptedPassword
)
$protectedByteArray   = [System.Convert]::FromBase64String($EncryptedPassword)
$decryptedByteArray   = [System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData]::Unprotect($protectedByteArray, $null, [System.Security.Cryptography.DataProtectionScope]::CurrentUser)
$base64pass           = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($decryptedByteArray)
$plaintextPass        = [System.Text.Encoding]::ascii.GetString([System.Convert]::FromBase64String($base64pass))
return $plaintextPass
}

Function Encrypt-SecretAccessKey {
param (
    [string]$PlaintextPassword
)
$base64plaintext      = [System.Text.Encoding]::ascii.GetBytes($PlaintextPassword)
$encryptedByteArray   = [System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData]::Protect($base64plaintext, $null, [System.Security.Cryptography.DataProtectionScope]::CurrentUser)
$encryptedPass        = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($encryptedByteArray)
return $encryptedPass
}


### Example calls

$testPassword="anythingYouWant"

$NewEncryptedPassword  = Encrypt-SecretAccessKey -PlaintextPassword $testPassword
$NewEncryptedPassword
$NewDecryptedPassword = Decrypt-SecretAccessKey -EncryptedPassword  $NewEncryptedPassword
$NewDecryptedPassword
```

Answer (score 0):

I've spent about 5 hours on this today trying to see if it's possible to get that encryption pinned down so that you can make your own DSN programmatically, and I haven't made much progress.

I've narrowed it down to an encryption function being called in libssl-1_1-x64.dll (in the bin install folder).
I've tried using RSA Encryption with a variety of padding schemes on the certificate provided with the install, but no dice. In fact, you can delete the certificate entirely and everything will still encrypt and decrypt normally. Just for the sake of trying, I also deleted everything in all of my certificate stores (before taking a snapshot) and it still worked just fine for both encrypting and decrypting.

Whatever encrypt function they're using to generate that value for saving under **SecretAccessKeyEncrypted** in the registry, it depends upon all but libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll to generate them.

It's not using a public key that gets installed in the Certificates store
it's not dependent upon an internet connection to encrypt and decrypt
it's definitely not calling KMS or anything like that

...so I'm just *guessing* that it's some kind of symmetric encryption with an obfuscated key buried somewhere in the source code that you wouldn't be able to get to without breaking the License agreement.

What stinks even more is that you can't use Powershell to add the DSN either, because Add-ODBCDsn hangs on run for the Amazon Redshift (x64) driver. For now at least, I have no more things to try... best of luck.